# Is there any way to avoid try/catch blocks when calling a method which may throw some exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have a method which may throw an exception, say:

```
public void myMethod() throws myException {
 //body
}
```

What should I do if I do not want to include try/catch when I invoke this method?

Comment: You can rethrow the error - same as this method does.

Comment: What should happen to the exception? Why are you trying to avoid a try/catch block?

Comment: The method from which you are calling from needs also to declare that it throws the exception.

Comment: i think the important question is what you want to happen, that is, what should happen if the method throws an exception - there should be some reason for that exception being thrown (which we cant know given current explanation, and hopefully not just "*I want to throw an Exception*"). And "not want to include try/catch" is very broad and invalid reason for coding IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.  Either you can make the calling method also throw the same exception, e.g.

```
public void caller() throws MyException {
    myMethod();
}
```

Or, you could refactor the `myMethod()` method to use a try catch block itself:

```
public void myMethod() {
    try {
        // body
    }
    catch (MyException e) {
        // do something
    }
}

public void caller() {
    myMethod();
}
```